# OpenGl ES: using many FBOs

Tags: opengl-es

I need to have an arbitrary number of passes, where each pass renders to some kind of a Buffer which is then used as an input texture to the next pass.

Currently, each Buffer is implemented by an FBO with a Texture attached to COLOR0. First I create the FBO (and the texture inside) with

```
glGenTextures(1, texIds, 0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texIds[0]);
// ... here goes the usual glTexParameterf stuff ...
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, mWidth, mHeight, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, null);
glGenFramebuffers(1, fboIds, 0);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboIds[0]);
glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, texIds[0], 0);
```

Then whenever I need to render to the Buffer I call

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, fboIds[0]);
```

and whenever I need to set the Buffer's contents as input to the next pass, I do

```
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texIds[0]);
```

and everything works.

The problem is that I read in numerous sources that the BindFramebuffer call is very slow (flushes the whole pipeline) especially on OpenGL ES targets which I work with. SongHo Ahn, for instance, clearly states that

> "(...) Switching framebuffer-attachable images is much faster than
>   switching between FBOs."

( http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_fbo.html )

Thus I am thinking to switch to a design where there's only 1 Framebuffer, and many Textures; and each time I need to render to a Buffer I'd only attach the given texture to the sole Framebuffer's COLOR0.

Do you think this is a good idea? Or maybe some totally different design would be best here - what about RenderBuffers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this NVIDIA presentation](https://developer.nvidia.com/sites/default/files/akamai/gamedev/docs/Porting%20Source%20to%20Linux.pdf) (page 65) you shouldn't swap the attachments on a single FBO:

> "Do not create a single FBO and then swap out attachments on it. This
>   causes lots of validation in the driver, which in turn leads to poor
>   performance."

This is because when you attach a new texture to the FBO's color attachment, the OpenGL driver has to check if the attachment is correct and the FBO is complete, which can be quite expensive if done often.

There is also a possibility to render to multiple color attachments at once but this is only available in OpenGL ES 3.0+.

But in general, the answer to your question is **no**. You should stick with using multiple FBOs instead of changing the attachments on it.

Answer (score 1):

In addition (and a bit of a contradiction) to the NVidia presentation linked to by MarGenDo, here's a link to the [OpenGL.org official documentation](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Framebuffer_Object_Extension_Examples#1_FBO_or_more) which seems to state (partly) the opposite:

> Is it better to make 1 FBO and bind your texture to it each time you
>   need to render to the texture? An FBO itself doesn't use much memory.
>   It is a state vector object. In terms of performance, each time you
>   bind, the driver needs to validate the state which costs CPU time.
>   Logically, it would be better to have 1 FBO per Render_To_Texture
>   (RTT). However, it has been found that you get a speed boost if your
>   textures is the same size and you use 1 FBO for them. If you have 10
>   textures that are 64x64 and 10 textures that are 512x64, make 2 FBOs.
>   One FBO for each group.

Answer (score 1):

Leszek's comments must be taken into context to complete the current accepted answer.

If one is using <  Opengl es 3.0, it is always better to keep FBO attachment same and changing the FBO. While changing FBO is costly; there is no need to escape it. Changing the underlying resource will only cause more additional work. The driver also had to verify the render ability of the new texture in addition to frame buffer completeness.

With 3.0+, one can attach multiple textures/Render buffers and use the draw_buffer_attachment effectively to render with minimal state overhead. The FBO or the GL_COLOR_BUFFER_ATTACHMENT does not need to change at all.